# Sorting tuple genereated by list comprehension in python

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, list-comprehension

I'm having trouble sorting individual tuple created by a list comprehension. 
Say we have:

```
words = [(a, b, c) for a in al for b in bl for c in cl]
```

Now I want to sort each tuple (a, b, c) by doing:

```
map(lambda x: sorted(x), words)
```

which gives me the error: 'tuple' object is not callable.

I also tried:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    out = [words[i][0], words[i][1], words[i][2]]
    print out.sort()
```

which prints a bunch of Nones.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably created a variable called `map` or `sorted`, overwriting the function of the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just sort the tuples as part of the creation:

```
words = [sorted((a, b, c)) for a in al for b in bl for c in cl]
```

Note that this will give you a list of lists, not a list of tuples, because `sorted` returns a list.  If you really want tuples you'll have to do

```
words = [tuple(sorted((a, b, c))) for a in al for b in bl for c in cl]
```